# How do I integrate codeigniter and log4php?

Tags: php, codeigniter, log4php

I want to integrate Log4php to my codeigniter application.

Is there a library in codeigniter to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using this: https://github.com/fukata/ci-log4php

Comment: Can you explain WHY you are using it?

Comment: because its easy to use and because i'm using other code from that guy

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. For the purpose of others looking for the answer to this question, Stack Overflow prefers to see more content than just a URL, which could break, rendering your answer useless. So, please add your reasons and how you're using it.

Answer (score 0):

We have been using log4php with CI as it gives us ability to keep an eye on error/notices while clients do NOT see them as clients get annoyed looking at those harmless notices.

We tried using Log4PHP directly with CI but it was bit tricky. To add to CTAPbIu_MABP's answer, fukata's ci-log4php is much simpler to integrate as it gives readily usable helper/libraries/config files that can be moved directly inside your application.

Here is a detailed blog entry about this.

http://tudip.blogspot.in/2012/05/log4php-with-codeigniter.html

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

for completer procedure of implementing log4php in CI refer the below link

[setting-up-log4php-with-code-igniter](http://roomforcreativity.wordpress.com/2012/06/14/setting-up-log4php-with-code-igniter/)

but I would give more preference to the inbuilt mechanism of CI used for logging error